# Printing Two C Columns One Sorted

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm working on taking 10 numbers as user input and having the input printed in two columns with one sorted column.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;
    int list[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    int sortedList[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    int i, j, temp;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        scanf("%d \n", &list[i]); {
            for(j = 0; j < NUM_ELEMENTS; j++){
                sortedList[j] = list[i];}
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        if(list[i] > sortedList[j]) {
                temp = list[i];
                sortedList[j] = temp;
                }
            }

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
    printf("%d %d\n", list[i], sortedList[j]);
    }

return 0;

 }
```

The first column prints correctly but the second column doesn't print the correct numbers. I'm fairly new at coding in C and can't seem to get this to work right. I've tried several variations of the provided code. The columns are also supposed to be side by side and labeled as well.

Comment: Interesting way to get UB.

Comment: You should try something simpler first - read an array as in the problem, then print it. Then perhaps assign its values to a second array while reading (hint - not need for a nested loop). From the errors in your code it seems that covering these basic steps would be important for you. Then attempt to print both arrays with labels and only afterwards think about sorting and how to implement a simple sort.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of bugs in the above code.

-**firstly**, looping constraints are wrong in scanning and assigning part

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        scanf("%d \n", &list[i]); {
            for(j = 0; j < NUM_ELEMENTS; j++){
                sortedList[j] = list[i];}  /* for i=0 why list[0] assigned to all sortedList[j] ?
        }
    }
```

Replace above one with

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
         scanf("%d", &list[i]);
         sortedList[i] = list[i];
}
```

-**Secondly**,sorting logic is not correct at all.

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
      if(list[i] > sortedList[j]) { /* what is sortedList[j] ? */
          temp = list[i];
          sortedList[j] = temp;
      }
 }
```

Replace above one with simple sorting technique logic for now but once become strong with basics check performance view also, which sorting method is better to use.

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS-1; i++) {
                for(j = 0;j < NUM_ELEMENTS-1-i; j++) {
                        if(sortedList[j] > sortedList[j+1]) {
                                temp = sortedList[j];
                                sortedList[j] = sortedList[j+1];/* you miss this */
                                sortedList[j+1] = temp;
                        }
                }
        }
```

-**Finally**, there is bug in print part also.

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
    printf("%d %d\n", list[i], sortedList[j]); /* what is j here ? you can use the same variable i for both. */ 
}
```

Replace above one with

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
        printf("%d %d\n", list[i], sortedList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Works as intended! Going to learn from some logical issues. Upvoted.